# kill com process on remote machine, determinate process startup arguments

Tags: process, command-line-arguments, kill

I want to kill com process on remote computer.

I tried taskkill but I cannot find how to det pid from com guid or startup arguments.

Then I tried following:

```
ConnectionOptions connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connectoptions.Username = @"YourDomainName\UserName";
connectoptions.Password = "Password";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + remoteComp + @"\root\cimv2", connectoptions);

//Define the WMI query to be executed on the remote machine
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_process where name = 'dllhost.exe' and CommandLine LIKE '%COMGUID%'");

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
                   ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
    {

        process.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);

    }
}
```

For some reason I cannot execute it because of RPC error (firewall is turned off)

I put it in own Webservice but I got "User credentials cannot be used for local connections"

I removed ConnectionOptions but I still cannot execute it because I get CommandLine is always null and I cannot determinate right dllhost.exe instance.

I used Process class int the webservice but sturtupinfo arguments are always empty.

How to get stutup arguments for different process or if any way to kill the process.